# Reliably sort jsonb keys

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a query that builds a nested jsonb object and returns that value as `original` and an encrypted version as `encrypted`.

I would like to replicate this behavior in python for testing but I cannot seem to find a way to order the keys in the jsonb object (that I can mimic in python via OrderedDict) before it gets cast as text and then encrypted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care about the ordering of the keys?

Comment: @Blender probably because the *strings* `'{"a":"b","c":"d"}'` and `'{"c":"d","a":"b"}'` are different (and will be different after encryption) even though they represent identical JSON objects.

Comment: @muistooshort is correct. I can't reliably encrypt the json (as a string) if I can't consistently reproduce it after being cast as a string.